# IOException: unexpected response from remote api

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm having exactly the same problem as this person:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/4y90M9NlWsA

but there are no responses and I can't see anything else on the internet that helps. Does anyone know why this would happen?

```
    RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions()
        .server("localhost", 8888)
        .credentials("blah@blah.blah", "");
    RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
    installer.install(options);
```

The stacktrace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: unexpected response from remote api: {rtok: null, app_id: MyCorrectAppId}

at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.getAppIdFromServer(RemoteApiInstaller.java:326)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.loginImpl(RemoteApiInstaller.java:278)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.login(RemoteApiInstaller.java:239)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.install(RemoteApiInstaller.java:106)
at uk.blah.blah.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:114)
```

Comment: Is the client a standalone Java application or a App engine application?

Comment: I'm running it as a standalone application. It shares code with an app engine app though.

Comment: It's the application ID. If you're using Eclipse, my answer might be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed you've set the `<application>` element inside [appengine-web.xml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig) to `MyCorrectAppId`. That's the problem. As Eugene rightly pointed out, the **ID must be all lowercase**, like `mycorrectappid`. Quoting Dan Sanderson's book *[Programming Google App Engine](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6cL_kCZ4NJ4C&pg=PA57&dq=%22application%20id%22%20lowercase%20app%20engine%20google&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LRN5UrP3GMTJ0QWW8oHoBQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22application%20id%22%20lowercase%20app%20engine%20google&f=false)*:

> *Because the application ID is used in the domain name, an ID can contain only lowercase letters, numbers, or hyphens, and must be shorter than 32 characters. Additionally, Google reserves every Gmail username as an application ID that only the corresponding Gmail user can register.*

If you are working in Eclipse, you need to remember that when setting up a new web application project (there is an option towards the bottom of the "New Web Application Project" dialogue that allows you to specify the ID instead of leaving it blank).

[image]

For a standalone environment, I think you're probably fine if you leave the ID blank (it will default to "no_app_id").

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Unfortunately I can't now go back to the original thread that had the issue, but hopefully a Google search will produce this page. :-)

Comment: @mjaggard Thank you for accepting the answer and for the bounty. I'm curious, with *"original"* you mean there is a thread out there that predates the one you mentioned on your question?

Comment: No, I'm referring to that thread. The group was closed and made read-only a while ago when GAE moved their support to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/remoteapi/RemoteApiInstaller.java?r=165#202) of the `RemoteApiInstaller.getAppIdFromServer` method the exception `unexpected response from remote api` can be thrown when no `app_id` property found in the response body. And it seems that in your case it is probable that `MyCorrectAppId` does not match the [PAIR_REGEXP](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/remoteapi/RemoteApiInstaller.java?r=165#33) pattern, i.e. it contains any characters other than digits, letters in lower case, tilde, underscore or minus sign.